# My mail_report: Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message: is not of type String

Tags: civireport, error, scheduling

I'm running civiCRM 5.30.0 on Drupal 7.

I've designed a report to be sent weekly. To test it, I manually ran mail_report and got the detail below. Where is type STRING required?

---

Parameters raw (from db settings):
instanceId=[ID of report instance] required
format=[csv or print] optional-output CSV or print-friendly HTML, else PDF

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:3:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:32:"[ID of report instance] required";s:6:"format";s:67:"[csv or print] optional-output CSV or print-friendly HTML, else PDF";}

Full message:
Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message:  is not of type String

---

Comment: I should add that I manually tested it because cron is not running yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it manually from the scheduled jobs screen you need to edit the mail report entry there and set those parameters. Normally you would set them in the specific command you use for cron for a specific report.

See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_mail_report. For getting the instance id that's a good point. There's a couple ways but one is to go to Reports -> All Reports and then hover over the View Results link and in the url that appears in the browser status bar it's the number after the word "instance", e.g. if it says `civicrm/report/instance/5?force=1&reset=1` then the id is 5.

Comment: Where can I find a syntax guide to make the corrections? And where do I find the "ID of report instance"?

Comment: Have updated answer.